# Strange behaviour when passing a struct property (slice) to a function that removes elements from it

Tags: go, slice

I've started learning Go these days and got stuck in trying to pass a struct property's value (a slice) to a function. Apparently it's being passed as a reference (or it holds a pointer to its slice) and changes made inside the function affect it.

Here is my code, in which `testFunction` is supposed to receive a slice, remove its first 3 elements and print the updated values, but without affecting it externally:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type testStruct struct {
    testArray []float64
}

var test = testStruct {
    testArray: []float64{10,20,30,40,50},
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test.testArray)
    testFunction(test.testArray)
    fmt.Println(test.testArray)
}

func testFunction(array []float64) {
    for i:=0; i<3; i++ {
        array = removeFrom(array, 0)
    }
    fmt.Println(array)
}

func removeFrom(array []float64, index int) []float64 {
    return append(array[:index], array[index+1:]...)
}
```

That outputs:

```
[10 20 30 40 50]
[40 50]
[40 50 50 50 50]
```

My question is: what is causing the third `fmt.Println` to print this strange result?

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/G8W3H085In

p.s.: This code is only an example. It's not my goal to remove the first elements of something. I just wanna know what is causing this strange behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually we don't know whether a given call to append will cause a reallocation, so we can't assume that the original slice refers to the same array as the resulting slice, nor that it refers to a different one.

To use slices correctly, it's important to remember that although the elements of the underlying array are indirect, the slice's pointer, length and capacity are not.

As a result, it's usual to assign the result of a call to append to the same slice variable:

```
array = append(array, ...)
```

So to sum up, to receive the desired result always remember to assign the append function to a new or the same slice variable.

Here is the corrected and working code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type testStruct struct {
    testArray []float64
}

var test = testStruct {
    testArray: []float64{10,20,30,40,50},
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(test.testArray)
    a := testFunction(test.testArray)
    fmt.Println(a)
}

func testFunction(array []float64)[]float64 {
    for i:=0; i<3; i++ {
        array = removeFrom(array, 0)
    }
    fmt.Println(array)
    return array
}

func removeFrom(array []float64, index int) []float64 {
    return append(array[:index], array[index+1:]...)
}
```

Check it the working code on <kbd>[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GUevGDbXxX)</kbd>.

---

Another solution is to pass the array argument via pointer reference:

```
func testFunction(array *[]float64) {
    for i:=0; i<3; i++ {
        *array = removeFrom(*array, 0)
    }
    fmt.Println(*array)
}
```

<kbd>[Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/_w4NFZAcBA)</kbd>

Comment: But how do I print the original slice values instead of the new ones in the third `Println`? Is there any way to prevent changes made to it's values inside the function from affecting it externally? Or perhaps a way to copy its original value before manipulating it inside the function?

Comment: But what I want is the third print to show the same as the first :P

Comment: @abel you might want to use `copy()`.  `copy(newSlice, slice)`

Answer (score 2):

The slice is a composite type. It has a pointer to the data, the length and the capacity. When you pass it as an argument you're passing those values, the pointer, the length and the capacity; they are copies, always.

In your case you modify the data within the slice when you call `removeFrom()`, which you can do because you've copied the value of a pointer to the original data into the func, but the length and capacity remain unchanged outside the scope of that function as those are not pointers.

So, when you print it again from `main()` you see the altered values but it still uses the original length and capacity as any changes made to those within the scope of the other funcs were actually on copies of those values.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a useful blog post about slices https://blog.golang.org/slices. It states this in particular.

> It's important to understand that even though a slice contains a
>   pointer, it is itself a value. Under the covers, it is a struct value
>   holding a pointer and a length. It is not a pointer to a struct.

The reason you see `[40 50 50 50 50]` is because you changed the values in the slice, but you did not alter the slice itself(it's cap and len)